# spring integration dsl configure idempotent receiver to identify duplicates

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am using DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE mode while consuming messages from queue, i need to detect duplicates and ignore them.

```
.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(activeMQConnectionFactory)
                        .destination(sourceQueue)
                        .configureListenerContainer(spec -> {
                            spec.sessionTransacted(false);
                            spec.sessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                        }))
                .transform(orderTransformer)
                .handle(orderService, "save")
                .get();
```

I have an idempotent receiver advice.

```
@Bean
public IdempotentReceiverInterceptor idempotentReceiverInterceptor() {
    IdempotentReceiverInterceptor idempotentReceiverInterceptor = new IdempotentReceiverInterceptor(new MetadataStoreSelector(m ->
            (String) m.getHeaders().get("JMSMessageId")));
    idempotentReceiverInterceptor.setDiscardChannelName("ignoreDuplicates");
    idempotentReceiverInterceptor.setThrowExceptionOnRejection(false);
    return idempotentReceiverInterceptor;
}
```

I am stuck with 2 things

1. How to i configure/call this advice in the
   Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter?
2. If i need the metadata store to be in oracle/mysql, how does the table look like any example links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Idempotent Receiver is definitely a matter of *consumer*, but not *producer*, which is `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()`. In terms of Spring Integration, of course.

If you don't want to pass duplicates to downstream, you need to configure such an `Advice` on the consumer after that `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()`. In your case it is `.transform(orderTransformer)`. So, the code might look like this:

```
.transform(orderTransformer, e -> e.advice(idempotentReceiverInterceptor()))
```

The  oracle/mysql `MetadataStore` is here - `JdbcMetadataStore` since `5.0`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-metadata-store

Comment: what is difference between having `.handle(idempotentReceiverInterceptor()).transform(orderTransformer)`and your suggestion `.transform(orderTransformer, e -> e.advice(idempotentReceiverInterceptor()))`

Comment: ??? The `IdempotentReceiverInterceptor` is not a `MessageHandler`. It is an AOP `Advice`. Therefore it can be applied only to some other message handling component. What makes you think differently? https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#idempotent-receiver

Comment: I understand now, the reason which made me think is `.transform(orderTransformer, e -> e.advice(idempotentReceiverInterceptor()))` gave compile error, it took me while to fix it to `.transform(orderTransformer, "methodName", e -> e.advice(idempotentReceiverInterceptor()))`

Comment: Yeah... It's not clear by your code what the type that `orderTransformer` is. Good to read that you have found a solution.

Comment: Thanks i was able to setup the metadata store for my ms-sql as well